# tensor notation surprise

Tags: notation, tensors

I'm trying to study tensors from several textbooks. 
One early example completely confuses me:

Islam, Tensors and their Applications, in the "Preliminaries" chapter, gives this example
(page 3, using summation convention):

> $a_{ij} x^i x^j  =  a_{11} (x^1)^2 + a_{22} (x^2)^2 +  \cdots + a_{nn} x^n x^n$

i.e. there are no "cross" factors. I would have thought instead it would be

> $a_{ij} x^i x^j  =  a_{11} (x^1)^2 + a_{12} x^1 x^2 + \cdots + a_{21} x^2 x^1 + a_{22} (x^2)^2 + \cdots$

i.e. like a quadratic form (in linear algebra terms).  The book looks appropriate for me, lots of worked examples, but sadly I'm stuck already!

Comment: This might be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Comment: The first expansion is true only if $a_{ij}$ is in diagonal form. Maybe that's implied somewhere. Otherwise, you get all cross terms.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a error in the book. Note that the book performs the expansion in two steps:

> $$ a_{ij} x^i x^j   =  a_{1j} x^1 x^j + a_{2j} x^2 x^j +  \cdots + a_{nj} x^n x^j \\
>                    =  a_{11} x^1 x^1 + a_{22} x^2 x^2 +  \cdots + a_{nn} x^n x^n $$

The first step has the cross products, as you correctly expected, but the second step just seems wrong unless you assume that $a_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$.
Kind of a bad error to have in the preliminary explanation of the notation.